# Unobtrusive JQuery not working in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've set an onclick event unobtrusively to one of my buttons which is working fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera. But in IE8 te script is never called (debugger statement is never executed).

The script:

```
$(function () {
    $('#template-button').click(function () {
        debugger;
        var $templateDdl = $('#templateDdl');
        var selTempID = $templateDdl.val();
        var url = $templateDdl.data('url');
        $.post(url, { selectedTemplateID: selTempID }, function (data) {
            $('#template').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

The button:

```
<input type="button" value="Verander template" id="template-button" />
```

The JQuery is in a seperate file called artsportaal.js which is loaded in the _Layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/IG/infragistics.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/IG/infragistics.loader.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/artsportaal.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It is being loaded as almost the last script.

Is this a well known issue with a work around? Have I done something wrong? Thanks for your time and interest in my question.

Comment: Perhaps the button attribute Id is coming twice on your html page. check it first

Comment: @devnull69 as a matter of fact, it works. Chrome starts pauses execution (that's weird...), whereas IE8 just ignores it, as it should be.

In JS you can write statements without assignments or executions as 'use strict'; 'lol'; or var x = 5; and then just x;

Comment: I learnt something new. There actually is a "debugger;" statement ... whoever invented this is ignoring all the standards and should be sued :D

Comment: I know that `debugger;` is a valid Javascript construct, but it shouldn't actually DO anything ... just like `x;` won't do anything after `var x=5;`

Comment: I'm new to the whole webdevelopment world. What is the standard for debugging javascripts then? I would very much like to comply. The quickest thing I found and which worked is the debugger statement, that's all. You focus on the wrong thing though, that is not my question... The script works perfectly in all the other browsers except IE8.

Comment: Do you have another element with `id="template-button"`, because different browsers have different DOM parsers and it might be that IE8 reads that other id first and does not bind it to element you want.

Comment: Or it could be that you load the script in `header`. Which means that your script executes before the html is written in `body`. jQuery unless used `.live()` will not bind to DOM elements that are run after the script is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works perfectly. As @ravisoni commented, I could have been because of name collision.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('#my_button').click(function () {
                alert('button got clicked!');
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="click_me" id="my_button" />
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** I edit to comment to @devnull69 as to "debugging;". Statements with no side efects are accepted in JS, and therefore the script does not crash because of that "debugging;"

This is valid JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#my_button').click(function () {
        'use strict';
        'or better, do not use strict';
        var x = 83;
        x;
        alert('button got clicked!');
    });
});
```

Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/SQgdK/1/

Comment: I'm afraid I was not entirely clear. With your example I get it to work aswell. But if I put your javascript function in my seperate .js file (as is my case) it does not. Remember, it works in all the other browsers. I have, for example, loaded the scriptfile in the  _Layout.cshtml... So that's not it.

Comment: Make sure you are loading the external .js AFTER you load the jQuery .js. It does not make any sense that it works together but not separately.

Comment: It's the last script that's loaded.

Comment: It works if you write the script directly on the document, but it does not work if you put it in an external file... uhm. If you are sure you load the two .js files in the right order, I would say the last idea I have is that you are not loading properly either of both of the two files. Have you tried with this configuration (2 files) in different browsers? are you sure it only fails in IE8? Check the paths, and open the page source (right click) and you'll see a hyperlink to the .js files. If you click on them and they don't bring you to the javascript code, you know where the error is.

Comment: Yes sir! I've checked on all browsers, else I wouldn't dare post that. I've updated my original post with the additional information. And I'll tell you something even beter! The code in DatePicker.js is working, because I checked it just now in IE8. I actually didn't have a problem untill a colleague asked me if I could run it in IE for a problem of his. Then I discovered my button was 'dead'.

Comment: Well... does the IE8 JS console gives you any error when the page gets loaded? the last idea I have left is that maybe one of the scripts you load apart from jquery and the file that has the code for the button event is crashing. Try to load only these two .js files, and if it still fails, load only jquery and in the other .js only the the function that interacts with the button.

Comment: I haven't checked what you suggested yet, because today when I wanted to work on the problem the popup with 'button got clicked!' was shown?! So I thought it was a cache problem. I commented your script and uncommented mine again. Still the popup 'button got clicked' was shown?! I stopped the ASP.NET development server. Still not correct. I even restarted visual studio. Still your script is run and not mine. While your script is in comments! Something weird with caching is going on...

Comment: If the old page is still loading, either you are having problems with caching (try control + F5), or you are really modifying one file, and checking another (it's stupid, but it has happened to me). After that, I'm quite positive that your problem with not firing the pop up in an external file is because one of your other .js file crashes when loading and stops the JS. Maybe a typo that modern browser can correct on the fly but not IE8. Beware of using the word "this" as variable in IE, since it is a member of the global object.

Comment: I marked you as an answer. It seems to be working fine now. I'm assuming it was a cache issue. Weird how the other browsers had no problems. Thanks for sticking with my question.